# Find name of attribute using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a site with selenium and need to get the individual user ids that are only in the element attributes. Below is a code snippet of what I am trying to pull from.

```html
<h4 class="message-name">
  <a href="/members/297754/" class="username " dir="auto" data-user-id="297754" data-xf-init="member-tooltip" id="js-XFUniqueId6">
    <span class="username--style6">carnaval</span>
  </a>
</h4>
```

I need to pull the `data-user-id`, so the end result would be `297754`.

How would I go about grabbing this attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

x = "//a[contains(@class,'username')]"
attr = "data-user-id"

items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, x)
for item in items:
        id = item.get_attribute(attr)
        print(id)
```

Comment: Are you sure that this works?

Comment: Ahh wait, sorry, this will not work. Let me edit my answer.